# draw circle around the arrow using pure css

Tags: html, css

I have a button which is created using pure CSS.

On mouseover the button an arrow animates from top to bottom.I would like to create a circle just outside the arrow. So the circle should contain the arrow.

I am not sure if it is possible or not. I did some Google research but didn't find a suitable thing.

```
<a href="#" class="button">
  <span>Hover Me</span>
</a>
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/DFNn9/)

Comment: should the arrow be there the whole time?

Comment: Have you tried 'border-radius:500px' ?

Comment: Ed yes the border should be there whole time.

Comment: Yes I have tried with the border radius but didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you, something like this:

```
.button span:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -18px;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: -19px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #000;
    transition: opacity 0.2s, top 0.2s, right 0.2s;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DFNn9/4/

Comment: @prisoner....Thanks for the solution.This is exactly what I wanted. I just need to do couple of changes.The bgcolor of the circle should be white and the circle border color should be orange.Let me try.

Comment: Hi..Me again!!...I am struggling with one thing.Not sure but if it  is possible so that the arrow(with circle) stays by default and when you mouseover the arrow(with circle) disappears. I made it happen by changing the hover class. But I lost the animation for default text.It's not moving to the right side. Here is the fiddle--http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/vHuDx/

Answer (score 0):

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFNn9/11/)

```
.button:hover span:after, .button:active span:after {
    transition: opacity 0.2s, top 0.2s, right 0.2s;
    opacity: 1;
    border-color: #e24500;
    right: 0;
    top: 62%;
     width: 20px;
     height: 20px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background-color: blue
}
```